# ASP.NET MVC Can I use an extra table to store user profile?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

ASP.NET MVC Can I use an extra table to store user profile? And how to do that?

Something I've done here:

I have a database table has userId name, email, password stuff.
I want to use all the information in this table for user authentication, and also for user profile. How can I do that in Asp.net Mvc2 project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SQL Membership provider](http://helios.ca/2009/04/22/aspnet-mvc-sqlmembershipprovider/)